# How select column at rune time using JPA (JPQL or Criteria API)?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql, criteria-api

I've searched here on SO and the web but couldn't find an answer to this problem. How do I write the following MySQL query using JPQL or JPA's Criteria API?

```
public String getLanguage(String language) { 
    String query = "SELECT i18n." + language + " AS translated FROM i18n";
}
```

I realise this specific query is meaningless, but the problem for me is to choose column dynamically. Ie select i18n.language where 'language' is chosen at run time.

I could imagine it to look something like:

```
public List getLanguage(String language) {
    return entityManager.createQuery(
        "SELECT l.:language FROM I18n i"
    ).getResultList();
}
```

but this doesn't compile.
Thanks

Comment: late though, but for runtime/dynamic selection you should got with Criteria API. It addresses this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with parameter, since the parameter can't be used to replace column name, but you can do it in a way similar to what you do in plain SQL

```
public List getLanguage(String language) {
    return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT i." + language + " as translated FROM I18n i").getResultList();
}
```

**EDIT**

One way to do it with parameter, but it's not really dynamical solution, you would have to hard code all the options

```
SELECT CASE WHEN :language = 'EN' THEN i.en WHEN :language = 'MK' THEN i.mk END as translated FROM I18n i"
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks for quick reply. But this is like SQL, as you said. There isn't "JPA-way" to do it? Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, I've updated the answer with an JPA-like example :)